# Nativescript IOS build Cacoapods could not find compatible versions for pod

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, nativescript, cross-platform

**I have Nativescript 8 app :**

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.2.0",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-zoomimage": "^4.3.6",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~14.2.0",
    "@nativescript/camera": "^5.0.13",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.3.0",
    "@nativescript/datetimepicker": "^2.1.11",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@nativescript/firebase-auth": "^2.4.4",
    "@nativescript/firebase-core": "^2.4.4",
    "@nativescript/firebase-firestore": "^2.4.4",
    "@nativescript/firebase-storage": "^2.4.4",
    "@nativescript/imagepicker": "^1.0.7",
    "@nativescript/local-notifications": "^6.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-image-zoom": "^4.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "nativescript-phone": "^3.0.3",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^14.2.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2.0",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.4.0",
    "@nativescript/preview-cli": "1.0.2",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.3.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.9",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~14.2.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.0"
  }
}
```

**After i try to run `ns build ios` :
ERROR :**

> Installing pods... Analyzing dependencies Pre-downloading:
> FirebaseFirestore from
> https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git, tag
> 9.6.0 Pre-downloading: QBImagePickerController from https://github.com/flypapertech/QBImagePicker.git, commit
> 47aa21d32f8e6db0df79b089ad64e43d498b5951 [!] CocoaPods could not find
> compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore":   In Podfile:
> FirebaseFirestore (from https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git, tag
> 9.6.0)
>
> Specs satisfying the FirebaseFirestore (from
> [https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git`](https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git%60), tag
> 9.6.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target. 'arch install' command failed.

**What should i change to make this build work ?** I can't even understand the error itself, can someone explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll probably get answers faster on the Nativescript Discord server.

I believe it's telling you that it can't find/install the proper pods from CocoaPods.

It's looking for pods compatible with an older minimum iOS version.

You can build your app for a newer minimum versions by placing

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 13.0;
```

in your build.xcconfig file.

Then run

```
ns clean
```

and try again.

If that doesn't work, you may also need to run

```
pod repo update
```